# How I can do automation testing of email templates(HTML/PDF)..?

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, html-email, email-templates

Does anybody know any tools to do automation testing of email templates(HTML/PDF) ? We have around 200 email templates with unique id which will be generated when a web service call is made. Email content, which may vary among templates, will be passed in xml.  Due to increased number of email templates, Regression Testing has became a pain if any code changes to web service is made. Currently we are using soapUI to test web service(Generate emails). Please let me know if any more details needed on whole setup.

Any help would be appreciated.!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, which is a way to automate the testing of 200 email templates, I would recommend using [Litmus's RESTful API](http://docs.litmus.com/w/page/18056603/Customer%20API%20documentation) for this.

We created a custom ExpressionEngine plug-in to automate email testing via a landing page. If you happen to be using PHP this [wrapper](https://github.com/geelweb/Litmus) was very helpful.

There's no reason the API couldn't be used to a larger number of tests.

The API's `results/show` method would allow you to capture the individual result images and then output those to PDFs.

You could use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/) to then generate PDFs of the results.

(http://docs.litmus.com/w/page/18056603/Customer%20API%20documentation)

Comment: We are already using Litmus for HTML email testing(previews). Didn't know they have an API which will allow us to do automation testing of email templates. Many thanks for the info.

Comment: Sure thing, we knew about it when we signed up and forgot it existed until the need arose. It works well. The biggest issue is the frequent unpredictability of which clients are down at any given time on Litmus.